# I am trying to get a context menu to appear in front of a 3D object

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, three.js

I am trying to make a situation wherein a context menu appears when you click on the mesh of a 3D object. Herein what I have currently:

[image]

But what is happening is that the context menu is appearing behind the 3D object and so it is not properly visible. I was wondering what could I do to make the context menu appear in front of the 3D object? The raycast part of my code is herein stated:

```
public raycast(e: MouseEvent): void {
        let mesh;

        const x = e.clientX - this.rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - this.rect.top;

        let scenePointer = new th.Vector2();
        scenePointer.x = (x / this.canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
        scenePointer.y = (y / this.canvas.clientHeight) * - 2 + 1;
        var intersect;
        // Determine the component in-focus using raycasting
        this.raycaster.setFromCamera(scenePointer, this.camera);
        const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu")
        var rightclick;
        if ((<any>e).which) rightclick = ((<any>e).which == 3);
        else if ((<any>e).button) rightclick = ((<any>e).button == 2);
        if (!rightclick) {
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                this.asmStateServ.focusedComponent = this.assemblyFetchServ.guidToName.get(intersects[0].object.name);
                mesh = intersects[0].object
                if ((<th.MeshPhongMaterial>mesh.material).color.getHex() != 0x00ff00) {
                    this.asmStateServ.lastColor = (<th.MeshPhongMaterial>mesh.material).color.getHex();
                    (<th.MeshPhongMaterial>mesh.material).color = new th.Color(0x00ff00);
                }
                else {
                    (<th.MeshPhongMaterial>mesh.material).color = new th.Color(this.asmStateServ.lastColor);
                }

            }
            else {
                this.asmStateServ.focusedComponent = '';
            }
        }
        else {
            if (intersects.length) {
                intersect = intersects[0].object;
                menu.style.left = x + "px";
                menu.style.top = y + "px";
                menu.style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                intersect = undefined;
            }
        }

    }
```

Any kind of help by modifying my part of the code would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Assuming you have the `<body>` somewhere, the simplest thing would be moving the whatever `id="menu"` element after the `<canvas>`. If that's not an option, try setting `z-index`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally worked with increasing the z-index.